# How to convert my metamask private key into 32 bytes hexa

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py, python, bsc

How to convert my metamask private key into 32 bytes hexa ?

i am using web3 to start trading on pancake but when i try to convert my bsc metamask phrase keys into hexa is like 150 bytes but require  32 bytes what to do?>

````
import time
import config as config
from web3 import Web3
 
PancakeABI = open('pancakeABI.py','r').read().replace('\n','')
 
bsc="https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())
 
#My own address to swap from
sender_address = "0x13AE8Bb065407595681034dDA97361424AF14C00"
 
#This is global Pancake V2 Swap router address
router_address = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E"
 
#always spend using Wrapped BNB
#I guess you want to use other coins to swap you can do that, but for me I used Wrapped BNB
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c")
 
#This is your private key info
private="how i can set my phrase keys 32 bytes while they are 150 bytes"
 
#Print out your balances just for checking
balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
print(balance)
 
humanReadable = web3.fromWei(balance,'ether')
print(humanReadable)
 
#Contract id is the new token we are swaping to
contract_id = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56")
 
#Setup the PancakeSwap contract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=PancakeABI)
 
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
 
start = time.time()
print(web3.toWei('0.02','ether'))
 
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
  1074184953676691292, # here setup the minimum destination token you want to have, you can do some math, or you can put a 0 if you don't want to care
  [spend,contract_id],
  sender_address,
  (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
  'from': sender_address,
  'value': web3.toWei(0.02,'ether'),#This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
  'gas': 250000,
  'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
  'nonce': nonce,
})
 
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))```
````

Comment: why do you need to convert your private key? you only need your private key to sign transactions locally if you don't have a node that you control that you are using the rpc endpoint of.

Comment: i am not using any node , i wrote my keys so its says non hexa decimal found so when i oonvet it its says required 32 bytes ,  so how i do sign my transaction locally? i want to trade in pancakeswap

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime i have edited my code

Comment: your privateKey should not have 0x at the start that's it. just make sure you write it right.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime there is no 0x it is started from 666 and its like moe than 100 alphanumric 0 to f

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime i tried to transfer my keys to hex from here

https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime do you have idea how do i convert my proper private keys into hex?

Comment: you don't need to change anything in the privatekey, private keys are 64 bytes, if it is more than that it maybe an encrypted one, but if you got it from metamask then it is not an encrypted one.